# Event Handler is executed more than once

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

When I use this snippet of code The MessageOutput.Text is set 2 times, which means that the code is executed twice since I don't set the MessageOutput.Text anywhere else. Whenever I get a new message, this method is called and it is supposed to update the UI. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
 async void MessageReceived(DatagramSocket socket, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs eventArguments)
    {
        uint stringLength = eventArguments.GetDataReader().UnconsumedBufferLength;
        string receivedMessage = eventArguments.GetDataReader().ReadString(stringLength);

        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            MessageOutput.Text += (receivedMessage + "\n");
        });
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the method isn't being called twice?

Comment: This method is called when i receive a new message `listenerSocket.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;` and in this case it displays the received message twice.

Comment: That does not change my question at all. Put a break point on the first line of `MessageReceived` and see if you hit it twice

Comment: Yes, it is called twice, but I have no clue why.

Comment: please edit your question and add the code where you add the event handler. If there is more than one place where you do so, please show them all.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679646/uwp-datagramsocket-multicast) I have posted a different question with the full code, so maybe you can take a look at it.

Comment: I also suspect the event handler is registered twice somehow, the code that contains the handler registration would be very helpful to see.

Comment: I agree with @MZetko that this is likely the issue. Is `StartListener_Click` being called twice?

Comment: I just checked and the `StartListener_Click` is called only once.

Comment: somewhere in your code that handler is being assigned a second time. You are going to have to hunt it down to fix the issue.

Comment: This is what i get when I click on Find all references `[Client001] void MainPage.MessageReceivedEvent(DatagramSocket, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs) (1 reference) Client001\MainPage.xaml\MainPage.xaml.cs - (88, 47) : listenerSocket.MessageReceived += MessageReceivedEvent;`

Comment: @Stefan Based on your other post, I see that you are doing multicast.  By any chance, do you have more than one network connection (e.g. a wired and wireless connection)?

Comment: Currently I am on my laptop and I am using the Wi-Fi only. In my other post you can find the whole code, so maybe if you have 5 minutes to spare you can try it on your computer. If you decide to try it, since this is UWP you will need Windows 10, VS2015 and Developer settings enabled (which I am sure you have all).

Comment: @Stefan Have you tried running the app from two separate machines?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that, since I only have one machine with Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening and how can I fix it

The most possible reason is, there are several [virtual network switches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd581798(v=ws.10).aspx) in your system.

For example, there are three virtual network switches in my Windows 10, just go to **Control Panel->Network and Internet->Network Connections**.
[image]

I will get three messages at the same time:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Received data from remote peer (Remote Address: " +
                    eventArguments.RemoteAddress.CanonicalName + ", Remote Port: " +
                    eventArguments.RemotePort + "): \"" + receivedMessage + "\"");
```

*Received data from remote peer (Remote Address: **169.254.146.116**, Remote Port: 22113): "Hello"
Received data from remote peer (Remote Address: **172.16.80.1**, Remote Port: 22113): "Hello"
Received data from remote peer (Remote Address: **10.168.177.14**, Remote Port: 22113): "Hello"*

Please type `ipconfig /all` in cmd to check the IPv4 addresses for these switches:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, all I had to do was disable my "vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)".

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the problem is in this line.

```
listenerSocket.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
```

Please add the code where you have binded this event handler. Because exceptionally this line executed 2 times. So that's why your event handler gets executed twice.Hence you have to figure it out why this event is binded twice and your problem would be resolved.
Hope this help !!!

Comment: This isn't an answer. You need to get enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: I don't get the reputation for answering to your question but THANKS for your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You should delete this answer.