# UDP UWP server + Mono2x client

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, udp, uwp

I have a really weird issue with communication between server and client using UDP protocol. Client is written in Mono2x (I use Unity 3D as my client) and creates UdpClient class instance:

```
        _udpClient = new UdpClient(9050);
        _serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_serverIp), _serverPort);
```

My server is UWP application I want to run on Raspberry Pi that is using DatagramSocket:

```
        _udpServer = new DatagramSocket();
        _udpServer.MessageReceived += ClientCheck;
        await _udpServer.BindServiceNameAsync(port.ToString());
```

I send data from client to server but with no luck. I checked with TCPView that data is send from my client application but never reaches the server. And now is the weird part. When I receive message from server first (I hardcode port to client), my client is able to send data with a success.

I am using same IPEndPoint to send data from client without any changes after receiving packet from server, it just starts working. Honestly, I have no idea what I could do wrong, so I will be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And now is the weird part. When I receive message from server first (I hardcode port to client), my client is able to send data with a success

This is a known issue which is filed based on this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39767527/5254458

It includes the issue's description and temporary workaround.

The corresponding is team is investigating it and I can not guarantee that when the fix will be delivered.

Comment: Thank you for help! Does this issue occur only when server and client are on same machine?

Comment: @user2586571 For the specified issue I mentioned, not only